# Error connecting to SQL with IIS 7

Tags: c#, iis-7, visual-studio-2015, ssms

While working in IIS I recently launched an application on there. When I try to "Browse" the application it throws out the following error which had been discussed earlier [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22244669/network-path-was-not-found-error-during-site-access) by another user:

```
The network path was not found

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The network path was not found

Source Error: 


Line 34:                 {
Line 35:                     EventLogger.LogEvent(ex);
Line 36:                     throw ex;
Line 37:                 }
Line 38:                 finally

Source File: c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\IBT\workspace\iLaundry.IBT\Data\DatabaseUpdater.cs    Line: 36 

Stack Trace: 


[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The network path was not found]

[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)]
   iLaundry.IBT.Data.DatabaseUpdater.GetCurrentVersion() in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\IBT\workspace\iLaundry.IBT\Data\DatabaseUpdater.cs:36
   iLaundry.IBT.Data.DatabaseUpdater.ExecuteUpdates() in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\IBT\workspace\iLaundry.IBT\Data\DatabaseUpdater.cs:188
   iLaundry.IBT.Data.IBTData..cctor() in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\IBT\workspace\iLaundry.IBT\Data\IBTData.cs:40

[ApplicationException: Cannot connect to the database]
   iLaundry.IBT.Data.IBTData..cctor() in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\IBT\workspace\iLaundry.IBT\Data\IBTData.cs:45
```

I have changed the connection string as the previous accepted answer suggested but it still didn't fix my problem. Here is the C# code used to connect the application with the database:

***C#:***

```
using iLaundry.Utilities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace iLaundry.IBT.Data
{
    internal class DatabaseUpdater
    {

        private string connectionString;

        internal DatabaseUpdater(string connectionString)
        {
            this.connectionString = connectionString;
        }

        internal Version GetCurrentVersion()
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sysobjects WHERE xtype='P' AND [name]='DatabaseVersion'", conn))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    if ((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() == 0)
                        return Version.Parse("0.0.0.0");
                    cmd.CommandText = "DatabaseVersion";
                    return Version.Parse((string)cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    EventLogger.LogEvent(ex);
                    throw ex;
                }
                finally
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        internal List<string> GetUpdates(Version currentVersion, Version targetVersion)
        {
            List<string> result = new List<string>();

            if (currentVersion == targetVersion)
                return result;

            #region 0.0.0.0 -> 0.0.0.1

            if (currentVersion == Version.Parse("0.0.0.0"))
            {

                // Create List Items with Table
                currentVersion = result.AddUpdate(Version.Parse("0.0.0.1"),
                    @"CREATE TABLE Account (AccountId int primary key identity(1, 1),
UserName varchar(50) not null,
Password varchar(50) not null,
StatusActive bit not null)",

                    @"CREATE TABLE Recharge (RechargeId int primary key identity(1, 1),
AccountId int not null references Account,
RechargeDateTime datetime not null,
ExpiryDateTime datetime not null)",

                    @"CREATE TABLE Branch (BranchId int primary key identity(1, 1),
BranchKey varchar(50) unique not null,
SyncKey uniqueidentifier unique not null)",

                    @"CREATE TABLE Service (ServiceId int primary key identity(1, 1),
OwnerBranchId int not null references Branch,
SyncKey uniqueidentifier unique not null,
Description varchar(200),
StatusActive bit not null)",

                    @"CREATE TABLE [Order] (OrderId int primary key identity(1, 1),
BranchId int not null references Branch,
ExOrderNumber varchar(50) not null)",

                    @"CREATE TABLE OrderService (OrderServiceId int primary key identity(1, 1),
OrderId int not null references [Order],
ServiceId int not null references [Service],
Quantity int not null)",

                    @"CREATE PROCEDURE DatabaseVersion AS SELECT [Version]='0.0.0.0'");
            }

            #endregion


            #region 0.0.0.1 -> 0.0.0.6

            if (currentVersion == Version.Parse("0.0.0.1"))
                currentVersion = result.AddUpdate(
                    Version.Parse("0.0.0.2"),
@"CREATE TABLE Subscription (SubscriptionId int primary key identity(1, 1),
ProviderBranchId int not null references Branch,
ConsumerBranchId int not null references Branch,
RequestDateTime datetime not null,
ApproveDateTime datetime,
RejectDateTime datetime)",
@"ALTER TABLE Branch ADD [Name] varchar(100) not null, IsProvider bit not null default 0, IsConsumer bit not null default 0",
"ALTER TABLE Account ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_Username UNIQUE (Username)",
"ALTER TABLE Branch ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_BranchKey unique (BranchKey)",
"ALTER TABLE Branch ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_SyncKey unique (SyncKey)"
                    );

            if (currentVersion == Version.Parse("0.0.0.2"))
                currentVersion = result.AddUpdate(Version.Parse("0.0.0.3"),
                @"ALTER TABLE [ORDER] ADD [DispatchNumber] int null, [OrderStatusId] int not null default 1",
                @"CREATE TABLE [OrderStatus] (OrderStatusId int primary key identity(1, 1),StatusDescription varchar(50) not null,StatusActive bit not null)",
                @"INSERT [dbo].[ORDERSTATUS] ([StatusDescription], [StatusActive]) VALUES (N'DispatchToProvider', 1)",
                @"INSERT [dbo].[ORDERSTATUS] ([StatusDescription], [StatusActive]) VALUES (N'ReceivedByProvider', 1)",
                @"INSERT [dbo].[ORDERSTATUS] ([StatusDescription], [StatusActive]) VALUES (N'InProgress', 1)",
                @"INSERT [dbo].[ORDERSTATUS] ([StatusDescription], [StatusActive]) VALUES (N'Ready', 1)",
                @"INSERT [dbo].[ORDERSTATUS] ([StatusDescription], [StatusActive]) VALUES (N'DispatchToConsumer', 1)",
                @"INSERT [dbo].[ORDERSTATUS] ([StatusDescription], [StatusActive]) VALUES (N'ReceivedByConsumer', 1)",
                @"INSERT [dbo].[ORDERSTATUS] ([StatusDescription], [StatusActive]) VALUES (N'ReadyForCollection', 1)"
                );

            if (currentVersion == Version.Parse("0.0.0.3"))
                currentVersion = result.AddUpdate(Version.Parse("0.0.0.4"),
                @"CREATE TABLE OrderStatusUpdate (OrderStatusUpdateId int primary key identity(1, 1),
OrderId int not null references [Order],
PreviousOrderStatusId int REFERENCES [OrderStatus],
NewOrderStatusId int NOT NULL REFERENCES [OrderStatus],
ChangeDateTime datetime not null)",
                @"CREATE TRIGGER TR_OrderStatusUpdate ON [Order]
FOR INSERT,UPDATE
AS
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted) BEGIN
        INSERT
        INTO    OrderStatusUpdate
                (OrderId, NewOrderStatusId, ChangeDateTime)
        SELECT  OrderId, OrderStatusId, GETDATE()
        FROM    inserted
    END ELSE BEGIN
        INSERT
        INTO    OrderStatusUpdate
                (OrderId, PreviousOrderStatusId, NewOrderStatusId, ChangeDateTime)
        SELECT  u.OrderId, u.OrderStatusId, i.OrderStatusId, GETDATE()
        FROM    deleted u
                INNER JOIN inserted i ON (u.OrderId = i.OrderId)
    END");

            if (currentVersion == Version.Parse("0.0.0.4"))
                currentVersion = result.AddUpdate(Version.Parse("0.0.0.5"),
                @"INSERT [dbo].[ORDERSTATUS] ([StatusDescription], [StatusActive]) VALUES (N'ReturnedByProvider', 1)");

            if (currentVersion == Version.Parse("0.0.0.5"))
                currentVersion = result.AddUpdate(Version.Parse("0.0.0.6"),
                @"DELETE FROM [OrderStatusUpdate]",
                @"DELETE FROM [OrderService]",
                @"DELETE FROM [Order]",
                @"ALTER TABLE [Order] DROP COLUMN ExOrderNumber, DispatchNumber",
                @"ALTER TABLE [Order] ADD ConsumerOrderNo varchar(50) NOT NULL, ConsumerDispatchNo varchar(50) NOT NULL, ProviderOrderNo varchar(50), ProviderDispatchNo varchar(50)",
                @"CREATE TABLE [OrderServiceAttribute] (OrderServiceAttributeId int identity(1, 1) primary key, [OrderId] int not null references [Order], [Kind] varchar(50) NOT NULL, [Value] varchar(50) NOT NULL)");

            if (currentVersion == Version.Parse("0.0.0.6"))
                currentVersion = result.AddUpdate(Version.Parse("0.0.0.7"),
                @"ALTER TABLE [Order] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Order_OrderStatus] FOREIGN KEY ([OrderStatusId]) REFERENCES [OrderStatus] (OrderStatusId)");

            if (currentVersion == Version.Parse("0.0.0.7"))
                currentVersion = result.AddUpdate(Version.Parse("0.0.0.8"),
                @"DROP TABLE [OrderServiceAttribute]",
                @"CREATE TABLE [OrderServiceAttribute] (OrderServiceAttributeId int identity(1, 1) primary key, [OrderServiceId] int not null references [OrderService], [Kind] varchar(50) NOT NULL, [Value] varchar(50) NOT NULL)");


            if (currentVersion == Version.Parse("0.0.0.8"))
                currentVersion = result.AddUpdate(Version.Parse("0.0.0.9"),
                @"ALTER TABLE [OrderService] ALTER COLUMN Quantity float NOT NULL");

            if (currentVersion == Version.Parse("0.0.0.9"))
                currentVersion = result.AddUpdate(Version.Parse("0.0.0.10"),
                @"CREATE TABLE [OrderServiceDispute] (OrderServiceDisputeId int identity(1, 1) primary key, BranchId int not null references [Branch], IsReceived bit NOT NULL, Comment varchar(max))");

            #endregion

            //Next Version to follow here
            return result;
        }

        internal bool ExecuteUpdates()
        {
            Version currentVersion = GetCurrentVersion();
            Version targetVersion = this.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Version;
            if (currentVersion >= targetVersion)
                return true;
            List<string> heal = GetUpdates(currentVersion, targetVersion);
            heal.AddUpdate(targetVersion);

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                try
                {
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    conn.Open();
                    foreach (string sql in heal)
                    {
#if(DEBUG)
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sql);
#endif
                        cmd.CommandText = sql;
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    EventLogger.LogEvent(string.Format("Successfully updated to version {0}", targetVersion.ToString()));

                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    EventLogger.LogEvent(ex);
                    return false;
                }
            }

        }
    }

    internal static class DatabaseUpdater_Extensions
    {
        internal static Version AddUpdate(this List<string> updates, Version newVersionNo, params string[] sql)
        {
            updates.AddRange(sql);
            updates.Add(string.Format("ALTER PROCEDURE DatabaseVersion AS SELECT [Version]='{0}'", newVersionNo));
            return newVersionNo;
        }
    }
}
```

If you have encountered this error before and was able to fix it I would appreciate any input into this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of struggling the solution to the question was to go into IIS and rather look in the `Connection String` tab instead of the SQL server itself. After the IIS had access to SQL I just needed to enable the connection string by changing the Data Source name as shown below:

[image]

After changing the `default connection` to the correct Data Source. The connection worked exactly as I wanted it to.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're connection string is now correct - and is pointing to the server then what user are you trying to connect to the database as?  If you are using Windows Authentication rather than SQL authentication then you will need to add the user that the application is running under to the database and ensure it has the necessary permissions.  The user you'll need to add is probably IISAPPPOOL/Default App Pool

Comment: I added the user to SQL and the user has all rights to SQL to access, update and delete but when I go back to ISS it is still the same existing error.